# Django crispy form itself is saving the form, but crispy fields is not saving to the database

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

This code is saving my form

```
    <form method="POST" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-container">
    {{ my_form|crispy }}
<button type="submit">Submit form</button>
    </form>
```

But when I use as_crispy_field, It is not submitting at all.

```
     <form method="POST" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-container">
        {{ my_form.lastName|as_crispy_field }}
           {{ my_form.firstName|as_crispy_field }}
           {{ my_form.middleName|as_crispy_field }}
           {{ my_form.birthData|as_crispy_field }}
           {{ my_form.nation|as_crispy_field }}
           {{ my_form.birthPlace|as_crispy_field }}
          <button type="submit">Submit form</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: Do you get an error? Please share the traceback. You might need to share your views.py, too, since the error could be there. The template looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="POST" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-container">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ my_form|crispy }}
    <button type="submit">Submit form</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation for better understanging.

Comment: You failed to add the csrf_token tag to the form. Add it and your code will work fine